# Kotlin Channel does not collect value

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-jetpack-compose, viewmodel

I'm trying to send a variable value from my ViewModel to my composable screen. I tried using the debugger to find out where it gets stuck. It seems like it sends the value but never actually receives it.

This is the code I'm using:

**NewEvent.kt**

```
@Composable
fun NewEvent(
    viewModel: NewEventViewModel = viewModel(), 
    navController: NavController
){
    val context = LocalContext.current

    LaunchedEffect(context){
        viewModel.newEventType.collect { eventType ->
            Toast.makeText(context, eventType.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}
```

**changeEventType() gets called here**

```
DropdownMenu(
    expanded = menuExpanded,
    onDismissRequest = { menuExpanded = false },
) {
    eventTypeList.forEach {
        if(it != viewModel.event.eventType &&  it != EventType.UNKNOWN) {
            DropdownMenuItem(
                onClick = { viewModel.changeEventType(it); menuExpanded = false },
                text = { Text(stringResource(context.resources.getIdentifier(it.toString().lowercase(), "string", context.packageName))) }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

**NewEventViewModel.kt**

```
private val newEventTypeChannel = Channel<EventType>()
val newEventType = newEventTypeChannel.receiveAsFlow()

fun changeEventType(newEventType: EventType){
    viewModelScope.launch {
        newEventTypeChannel.send(newEventType)
    }
}
```

I downloaded a sample project from GitHub using this exact implementation and it worked, I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: Please share the piece of code where `changeEventType` method gets called

Comment: I don't see the NewEvent composable function being called. Make sure that it is present among your composition context

Comment: `changeEventType(it)`  is inside of the NewEvent composable. The only way I can access the dropdown menu is through that composable

Comment: I proposed alternative solution for you. It seems like your NewEvent composable is not getting called. So it may be the reason that event is sent but not received

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display toast message, you don't have to create separate composable function for it. Since Toast is dynamic and does not need to be recomposed, you don't need composable function for it.

It would be more clear and better to implement it like this (in one composable function)

```
val context = LocalContext.current

LaunchedEffect(context){
    viewModel.newEventType.collect { eventType ->
        Toast.makeText(context, eventType.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}

DropdownMenu(
    expanded = menuExpanded,
    onDismissRequest = { menuExpanded = false },
) {
    eventTypeList.forEach {
        if(it != viewModel.event.eventType &&  it != EventType.UNKNOWN) {
            DropdownMenuItem(
                onClick = { viewModel.changeEventType(it); menuExpanded = false },
                text = { Text(stringResource(context.resources.getIdentifier(it.toString().lowercase(), "string", context.packageName))) }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree, that would be cleaner, however I need to `collect` the eventType in another composable. The toast message is just for testing purposes. For now I decided against routing this through the viewmodel and created a mutableState which takes care of the change

Comment: @BlazeCodeDev I understand, so you need to make sure that your composable is called and composed. You can place method calling in the same method, where dropdown menu is defined